# В c# как сделать один код для нескольких атрибут?

Tags: c#, unity3d

С# недавно начал изучать. Для Unity создал ScriptableObject который отвечает за разные темы игры. Тема состоит из разных элементов, элемент может быть один GameObject расположения элементов или дополнительные GameObject для ориентаций экрана.

```
public class ThemeData : ScriptableObject
{

    [SerializeField] public DeviceTheme ODefault;
    [SerializeField] public DeviceTheme OPortrait;
    [SerializeField] public DeviceTheme OLandscape;

    [NonSerialized] public bool orientationPortrait;

    [Serializable]
    public class DeviceTheme
    {
        public GameObject HeaderForm;
        public GameObject MenuForm;
        public GameObject TextForm;
    }

    public GameObject getHeaderForm
    {
        get
        {
            var temp = (orientationPortrait) ? OPortrait.HeaderForm : OLandscape.HeaderForm;
            return (temp == null) ? ODefault.HeaderForm : temp;
        }
    }

    public GameObject getMenuForm
    {
        get
        {
            var temp = (orientationPortrait) ? OPortrait.MenuForm : OLandscape.MenuForm;
            return (temp == null) ? ODefault.MenuForm : temp;
        }
    }

    public GameObject getTextForm
    {
        get
        {
            var temp = (orientationPortrait) ? OPortrait.TextForm : OLandscape.TextForm;
            return (temp == null) ? ODefault.TextForm : temp;
        }
    }
```

Для примера скинул только три GameObject там их больше.
Как мне упростить код в get чтобы не повторять каждый раз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сериализатор используемый `unity`, сериализует `public` по дефолту, атрибут `[SerializeField]` для `private` полей, о чем можно прочесть в документации [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html). `public` полей класса в принципе быть не должно.

То есть для каждого объекта нужно дописывать поле `DeviceTheme`, добавлять свойство в `DeviceTheme` и еще писать новый скрипт который достает конкретное поле... зачем? Почему просто не работать с каким-нибудь идетификатором?

```
[Serializable]
public class ThemeElementTemplate
{
    [SerializeField] private string _name;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _default;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _portrait;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _landscape;

    public string Name => _name;

    public GameObject GetElement (DeviceOrientation orientation)
    {
        if (_portrait != null && IsPortable(orientation))
            return _portrait;
        else if (_landscape != null && IsLandscape(orientation))
            return _landscape;
        else
            return _default;
    }

    private bool IsPortable (DeviceOrientation orientation) => orientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait || orientation == DeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown;
    private bool IsLandscape (DeviceOrientation orientation) => orientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || orientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight;
}
```

---

Добавление нового элемента, это просто добавление в список, чем бы он там ни был

```
public class ThemeElementCollection : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private ThemeElementTemplate[] _elements;

    public ThemeElementTemplate GetElement (string name)
    {
        return _elements.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == name);
    }
}
```

---

И тупо обращаться по идентификатору в виде ключа

```
public class ThemeElement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _elementName;
    [SerializeField] private ThemeElementCollection _elementCollection;
    private ThemeElementTemplate _template;
    private GameObject _current;

    public void Start ()
    {
        _template = _elementCollection.GetElement(_elementName);
        UpdateElement(Input.deviceOrientation);
    }

    public void OnOrientationChange (DeviceOrientation orientation)
    {
        UpdateElement(orientation);
    }

    private void UpdateElement (DeviceOrientation orientation)
    {
        if (_current != null)
            Destroy(_current);
        if (_template != null)
        {
            GameObject template = _template.GetElement(orientation);
            if (template != null)
                _current = Instantiate(template);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Только встает вопрос... а нафига `ThemeElementCollection` нужен как посредник? почему сразу не передавать `ThemeElementTemplate` в `ThemeElement`? И никакие ключи не будут нужны...

А зачем вообще разделять `ThemeElementTemplate` и `ThemeElement` на две ответственности? Почему нельзя обойтись одним единственным `ThemeElement`?

Comment: Благодарю! Переделал как здесь, всё получилось. И почему у меня мысли даже не было так сделать объект для ориентаций, а потом каждому свойству их добавить.


_А зачем вообще разделять ThemeElementTemplate и ThemeElement на две ответственности? Почему  нельзя обойтись одним единственным ThemeElement?_


Нужно сделать несколько тем с одинаковым набором элементов.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThemeData : ScriptableObject
{
    public DeviceTheme ODefault;
    public DeviceTheme OPortrait;
    public DeviceTheme OLandscape;

    [NonSerialized] public bool orientationPortrait;

    public DeviceTheme GetTheme()
    {
        var theme = orientationPortrait ? OPortrait : OLandscape;
        return (theme == null) ? ODefault : theme;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DeviceTheme
    {
        public GameObject HeaderForm;
        public GameObject MenuForm;
        public GameObject TextForm;
    }
}

public class UseTheme : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ThemeData _themeData;

    private void Awake()
    {
        var theme = _themeData.GetTheme();

        Instantiate(theme.MenuForm);
        Instantiate(theme.HeaderForm);
        Instantiate(theme.TextForm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, так не получится так как у некоторых элементов только ODefault вариация, а у некоторых есть OPortrait или OLandscape.